# Ansible: creating docker containers from a variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a variable structure set up as follows:

```
  container_traefik:
    image: 'traefik:latest'
    networks:
      ...
  container_oauth:
    image: 'thomseddon/traefik-forward-auth:latest'
    ...
```

and another variable to define the status of these containers:

```
enable_traefik: true
enable_oatuh: true
...
```

My current playbook has a task for each container like this:

```
 docker_container: "{{ container_traefik }}"
 when: "enable_traefik | default(False)"
```

I started looking into running this in a loop, but I have not been able to get it right.
I changed the variable structures to the following:

```
containers:
  traefik:
    image: 'traefik:latest'
    ...

enable:
  traefik: true
```

And tried to create them in a playbook like this:

```
docker_container: "{{ item.value }}"
when: "{{ enable.{{ item.key }} }}"
loop: "{{ containers }}"
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, among the many other combinations I have tried.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to use a `dict` as the entirety of a task the way you're doing it; I think you still have to create yaml keys that reference the jinja2 fields. You may be able (a) create a custom task that does what you're doing (b) write out a temp file and then [`include_tasks:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/6/user_guide/playbooks_reuse.html#re-using-files-and-roles)

Comment: If I do remember properly, it was possible in the `args` parameter, but has been disabled a while ago due to the obvious security concerns it raises.

Comment: [It is entirely possible but raises a warning](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/0fb0296e42bb99d71386d72427c8339a) (edit: just tested with core 2.13 and it still works).